# How to give permission within inAppbrowser in ionic App

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

i have a website which takes microphone and video permission in phone's browser but when i open it in inAppbrowser it didn't ask for permission .and i have given all the permissions from App setting but it didn't work so please any one suggest how to ask permission in inAppbrowser.

Answer (score 0):

Add cordova whitelist plugin and cordova inappbrowser plugin. 
The whitelist plugin will implements a whitelist policy for navigating the application webview on Cordova.
[Cordova whitelist plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/)

You can show helpful articles, videos, and web resources inside of your app. Users can view web pages without leaving your app easily bu using cordova inappbrowser plugin
[cordova inappbrowser plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/index.html)

Update:
Use this to request permission in the runtime
[cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) Also make sure u run it in real device and not on emulator.

Comment: i have already add Cordova whitelist plugin . but i want it to ask microphone and video permission when websites load in it .

Comment: try this, it will ask for permission in the runtime, but it requires native environment. make sure u run the application in real devices

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin

Comment: above link will ask permission for App but Website has its own permission which should ask in InAppbrowser when it loads in it .i want to get permisiion within InAppBrowser.

Comment: I think that has to done in the website, once the inappbrowser is loaded and everything that run inside the inappbrowser is outside the premises of the app. share more details or screenshots for better understanding

Comment: you are correct but what i want is do within the InAppBrowser .